# I can't access any antivirus site

Tags: windows-xp, usb, anti-virus, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

My system has got infected. I want to download and install an antivirus. I can't access any antivirus site. I have checked the host file. It is not allowing the USB drive too. What options I have now? Apart from these two, my system is working fine. Operating system : windows xp sp2.
EDIT : have scanned by malwarebytes. Did not find anything.

Comment: Your best option would be an offline scan from a Live CD.

Comment: I can't get the live CD thing. What type of live CD I have to use? Can you give me a link to create a live CD?

Comment: For example: [AVG Rescue CD](http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd). See the post I linked above for a bit more, but the AVG one is quite good.

Comment: @Nara - Be sure to update to SP3 once you fix your broken installation.

Answer (score 0):

Download antivirus software on a bootable CD image (or USB drive image) *using a different PC*. The malware on your system is preventing you from downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if you have Internet connectivity by opening a command box, and ping 8.8.8.8 (a Google DNS server). If you can, the proceed to the next step.

Check in Control Panel>Internet Options>Connections>LAN Settings and make sure that none of the boxes for proxies are checked. Then try again.

Comment: I can surf the internet. and the boxes are not checked.

Comment: I would also try combofix and Hitman Pro. Both have solved similar problems for me.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/anti-virus/combofix

http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=hitman+pro&platformSelect=Windows&tag=srch&searchtype=downloads&filterName=platform%3DWindows&filter=platform%3DWindows

Answer (score 0):

At http://www.volatileminds.net/node/6/release you will find a handy live CD that should allow you to scan your system and clean infections. I would recommend that you download and burn this CD on a different PC than the one you have infected. Then read through any documentation on that site, especially about updating virus patterns. Once you have the CD burned, put it into the infected computer and boot to it.